# Why is variable from one js file getting undefined when sent to another js file

Tags: javascript, node.js, stripe-payments

Currently, I have this code block which is the back-end for my Stripe setup. On the callback function, I'm setting a variable equal to the amount that gets charged to the user's card. I then want to send this value into another route file so that I can res.send() the amount into the browser.

When I try to do this, the variable somehow gets set to undefined from point a to point b.

```
router.post('/charge', function(req, res, next) {
    var token = req.body.stripeToken;
    var chargeAmount = req.body.amount[0];
    var charge = stripe.charges.create({
      amount: chargeAmount,
      currency: "usd",
      source: token
    }, function(err, charge) {
      if(err) {
        return console.log(err);
      }
      module.exports.theAmount = charge.amount;
      res.redirect('/users/dashboard');
    });
});

module.exports = router;
```

Here's the code from the route file that I'm trying to get the charge amount into:

```
var stripeFile = require('stripe');

router.get('/dashboard', isLoggedIn, function(req, res, next) {
  var messages = req.flash('error');
  res.render('users/dashboard', {messages: messages, hasErrors: messages.length > 0});
  console.log(stripeFile.theAmount);
});
```

Comment: Pass it as a parameter? Bear in mind if more than one person uses the app that having a single variable will cause significant issues.

Comment: @DaveNewton, I found a way to get the variable into the route file but how can I display this variable in the browser? It's currently inside of a router.get( ); for the page that I want it to be displayed on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot program this way.  Your server handles requests from lots of different users.  Trying to stuff the `charge.amount` into a module global so that you can then use it later in another request after a redirect is simply buggy and inappropriate coding that, even if it worked once, is guaranteed to have race conditions as soon as more than one user is using your site.  You can never program this way.

You haven't explained the entire problem here, but in general it would be better to solve your design issue without using a redirect.  That would keep you from having to find some user-specific place to store the `charge.amount` while you wait for the redirected request to come back again.  If you must store it somewhere, then you need to either use the `flash` module or you should create a session object for each user and store the data in the session (flash does something similar, but does it only for the "next" request from that user).  The session is tied to the user via a cookie so when the next request comes in from the redirect, the session middleware can identify the cookie, look up session object that belongs with that cookie and then your request handlers can have access to any data you've put in that user's session (such as the `charge.amount` value).

What would be better would be to just return the content directly from the `.post()` handler.  You already have the `charge.amount` value right there in that request handler so you could easily render a template using that value and return that content to the browser after the post.  Then, there's no need to store that value anywhere on your server waiting for some future request.

Comment: So after I save the charge amount into the user's session, how would I go about using that value in the browser to display like "Credits: $10.00"? The session expires so that value will not always be there, correct?

Comment: @kolbykskk - Permanently saved data for a user needs to go into a database on your server where it can be queried at any time.  Session data is for "the duration of a session" which can be a few minutes or many days, depending upon the lifetime of the session cookie and how long your server saves session data.